# How to update with strong parameter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strong-parameters

### What I want to do

My application has `Order` model and `List` model.
`List` model is Order's child.

`Order` has `total` column.
`List` has `price` and `quantity` columns.

I want to update the `total` of the `Order` by adding the subtotals of each `lists` line together.

### What I did

Here is my orders_controller.

```
def update
    @order = Order.find(params[:id])
    @order.total = @order.total_price
    if @order.update(order_params)
      redirect_to orders_path, notice: 'The order has been updated.'
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end
```

Here is my order.rb(model)

```
  def total_price
    lists.to_a.sum { |list| list.subtotal }
  end
```

To update total price, I set `@order.total_price` to `@order.total`.
But as you see, it updated with strong parameter(`order_params`).
I couldn't resolve how to update with total price.

What should I do?

### Environments

- ruby2.7.2
- rails6

Comment: What parameters do you have in order_params?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do it.

```rb
# One is just to do it on separate lines.
@order.update(total: @order.total_price)
@order.update(order_params)

# Merge with order_params
@order.update(order_params.merge(total: @order.total_price))
```

Finally the most Rails way is probably to use a `before_save` on the model

```rb
# Order.rb
before_save do
  total = lists.to_a.sum { |list| list.subtotal }
end

# orders_controller.rb
# just to
@order.update(order_params)
```